# weird whitespace color for source code htmlized from htmlize.el

Tags: emacs, org-mode, htmlize.el

I use org-mode to generate html pages and htmlize.el to render the syntax highlighting for the code block in the org files. The thing is that htmlize seems grab the the background color of my emacs color theme and use it to color the white spaces (see the pic below) instead of leaving them as untouched. Anyone else has this problem? how to change that?

[image]

Comment: Please provide links to third-party libraries.

Comment: It is a well known package and used by org-mode by default - http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el.cgi

Comment: Do you not want it to use your colour theme?

Comment: not for the whitespace. as you can see, it's disturbing